# Android client to connect with websocket server using Spring

Tags: android, spring, messaging, stomp

I want to send and receive messages (e.g. via STOMP) from/to my server using Spring.
On the server-side I got following code from the [Spring Documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/).

Is there a working android client (with code sample) how to communicate with the server? My target is to connect devices to each other via Internet to make a real-time game. By the way, are there other good approaches to get it started except via websockets?

Answer (score 2):

Another approaches:

1. [Android cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)
2. [Socket IO](http://socket.io/)
3. [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.html)

Websocket libraries:

1. [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)
2. [android-websockets](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets)
3. [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)

and many more.

Comment: I'm aware of GCM and XMPP, but what about the message capacity using those frameworks? Let us assume two people play a match, where they are firing thousends of messaging within several minutes. Does GCM handle it without limitations? And what about the messaging speed?

Answer (score 0):

The code is incomplete, there's no spring boot stomp configuration and you don't specify how you persist the object response.

I'm working on an Android stomp over WebSocket client. I suggest you check what the client the receive and how it payload string is converted into the object.

My project is still a work in progress, but it could be useful, I hope.

- [spring boot backend](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-backend)
- [android client](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-android)